# x64 logical AND of packed 32 bit floating points

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

This is the description:

> Performs a bitwise logical AND of the four or eight packed single-precision floating-point values from the first source operand and the second source operand, and stores the result in the destination operand.

> Opcode:
> 0F 54 /r
> ANDPS xmm1, xmm2/m128

> Description:
> Bitwise logical AND of xmm2/m128 and
> xmm1.

The *Opcode:* says `xmm1` first and the *Description:* says `xmm2/m128` first. So which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what's unclear. The description you quoted applies to the 3 operand form, you need to consider this paragraph for the 2 operand version:

> 128-bit Legacy SSE version: The second source can be an XMM register
>   or an 128-bit memory location. The destination is not distinct from
>   the first source XMM register and the upper bits (VLMAX-1:128) of the
>   corresponding YMM register destination are unmodified.

As such, the instruction does: `xmm1 = xmm1 & xmm2/m128`.
Due to the fact that bitwise `AND` is commutative, that's the same as `xmm1 = xmm2/m128 & xmm1`. The important thing is that `xmm1` is the destination.